# Wordpress customizer works perfectly in the customizer interface but doesnt in the actual design

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I recently RESET customizer setting with wp customizer plugin, did this on purpose to know certain error theme users would get on a fresh install of the theme, and I found out that on the customizer interface everything works well but when I actually load my design, I get a total different result.

Here is what it looks like

[image: Customizer result]

Blog result after customizer resets

[image: Blog actual result]

Here is the code i am using to change in settings from the customizer.php option ( dont think there is anything wrong with my settings pattern)

```
  $wp_customize->add_setting(
      'sq_hide_blog_info',
      array(
          'default'         => true,
      )
  );

     $wp_customize->add_control(
        new Toggle_Checkbox_Custom_control(
            $wp_customize,
            'sq_hide_blog_ctr',
            array(
                'description'    =>    __( 'Display Site name / Description' ),
                'label'    =>    __( 'Check here' ),
                'section'  => 'custom_footer_text',
                'settings' => 'sq_hide_blog_info',
                'type'     => 'checkbox',
                'section'  => 'sq_nav_design'
            )
        )
   );
```

here is what i am using to change options in the actual code.

example

```
 <?php if(get_theme_mod('nav_type_select') == 1): ?>
                <?php include get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/header/header-1.php'?>
                <?php else: ?>
               <?php include get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/header/header-2.php'?>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

The above settings is a check box, and default output set to 1, and I meant that, if nav 1 is selected then output it else, output nav 2 as default, if nav 1, is not selected then output nav 2, things was working fine until i reset the customizer default, which i guess would pull same error when i get a fresh install.

i know the settings in the code doesn't tally with the one in the customizer.php just using this for reference purpose.

i am solely depending on the customizer default to output value in the theme, with no fallback .

my instinct is telling me that the issue is from the way i placed my if statement , cause i used that pattern through out my code.

Thanks in advance, i would truly appreciate your help.

To be clear: i need help in , checking if my if else pattern is correct, if yes, then any work around to make the customizer actually update the new settings in the default page.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix this

this worked for me, even if all settings was refreshed

if (  get_theme_mod('my_banner_setting', 1) == 1 ) {

```
// proceed
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Theme modification name in get_theme_mod()

Try this snippet

```
<?php if( checked( get_theme_mod( 'sq_hide_blog_info', true ), true, false ) ) : ?>
 <?php include get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/header/header-1.php'?>
<?php else : ?>
 <?php include get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/header/header-2.php'?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks budyd, but  by defualt whats the output or wordpress checkbox,1 or 0 / true or false ?

Comment: Hi, 
You are using **custom control** so It's up to your control `Toggle_Checkbox_Custom_control`
I think it's true/false because you are passing **true** in the default value.